# Types of Spring configuration in theory

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I would like to ask for explanation of Spring configuration types?

Here is what I know but I am confused by what I have found here on stack and other places.

1. XML based configuration
2. Java based configuration
3. Annotation based configuration (this is what I am interested about)

I have read a lot of articles or opinions that there are basically only two configuration options (XML and Java). So what is wrong when I consider Annotation based config as a third option? I asssume that this option is available only when I use XML based configuration using:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

So is that why some people does not consider Annotation based config as a third options because it is dependent on XML (or Java) config?

I have one more questions:

Can I use Annotation approach by using Java based configuration? I was not able to find how to enable it using Java. (maybe using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`??)

I consider this scenario using Spring Core. When we are talking about SpringBoot I assume there is Annotation config enabled by default in `@SpringBootApplication` annotation?

Thank you!

Comment: you missed `spring-fu` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right in the general sense, I refer you to this small section in the official docs for spring [https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html]

Here you will see an example of using XML configurations using the

```
 <beans>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="com.acme.AppConfig"/>
 </beans>
```

and JAVA spring component scanning

```
    @Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

     private final SomeBean someBean;

     public AppConfig(SomeBean someBean) {
         this.someBean = someBean;
     }

     // @Bean definition using "SomeBean"

 }
```

You are also right about springboot @SpringBootApplication I contains @Configuration, @ComponentScan and @EnableAutoConfiguration to scan and configure your beans